# Setting iFrame source to a png file

Tags: asp.net, firefox, iframe, png

I have an iFrame that I use to display different media types by setting the "src" attribute. When I set the src to a .png file type however, Firefox does not render the image for me, but instead asks the user if they want to download the image.

Is there a way to force it to render?  Is this a client issue / feature or is it something I've missed?

```
<iframe id="ctl00_mainContent_uxEditClient_ifrmThumb" width="100px" height="100px" src="http://localhost:54468/Docs/Media/Partners/Logos/logo.png">
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body></body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

Comment: What headers are being sent alongside the image? (Although it could be that this is simply FF's default behaviour. Any chance of embedding it in a page?)

Comment: Why is there an `<html>` tag _inside_ the `<iframe>` tag?

Comment: Why are you displaying an image inside an IFRAME and not as an `<img>` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `src` property of an `iframe` is not meant to be an image but rather an URL of page containing HTML. Firefox is asking you to download the image because the server is writing the image bytes to the response stream.

Use an `img` element to display images.

Answer (score 2):

I tested your code but using a different image source:

```
 <iframe id="ctl00_mainContent_uxEditClient_ifrmThumb" width="100px" height="100px" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7a/Basketball.png">
 <html>
      <head></head>
      <body></body>
 </html>
 </iframe>
```

I think the problem is not related to Firefox or HTML, I guess it is the header your server is sending. HTTP header may force the browser to download instead of visualizing.

Please test my code in your specific Firefox version.

Comment: I agree. Test the header that's coming back from the PNG request.